# Very large .csv file. Convert to array and use, or insert into Databsase

Tags: php, sql, csv

I have a very large .csv file I download from a website to populate an online store. (4 thousand of entries, with 10 fields each)

I need to be able to manipulate the data (sort by price, show by category etc).

Is there a standard practice on how to handle this amount of data?

Reading the .csv file and converting it to an array is very slow.

It seems like it might be best to just insert all the data into a SQL table, and use it as normal, but I would have to re populate it every few days.

Can I save an array directly to disk, and would it be quicker than a table?

Comment: I think the usual thinking is that a table would be faster then reading from disk. Not to mention it give you relationships down the road and can do the manipulation in SQL. I would suggest looking into Dencker's answer with a cron job running a script with curl to get the file.

Comment: please amend to specify the database type : mysql, oracle, ms sqlserver, etc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you're using MySQL, you could look at [`LOAD DATA INFILE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/load-data.html). Something like:

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'path/to/your/file.csv' INTO your_table;
```

You can specify line- and field delimiters with `FIELDS TERMINATED BY` and `LINES TERMINATED BY` if you need to.

Create indices on the fields you need to query on.

On a side note, 4000 entries with 10 fields each is actually a very small dataset - unless of course every field is a 1G blob.

Answer (score 0):

You can just do the following..

```
<?php

try{

$handler = fopen('pathtoFile','r');
$conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);

// set the PDO error mode to exception
$conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
// prepare sql and bind parameters
$stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO YOURTABLE(firstname, lastname, email) VALUES (:firstname, :lastname, :email)");

$stmt->bindParam(':firstname', $firstname);
$stmt->bindParam(':lastname', $lastname);
$stmt->bindParam(':email', $email);

while( ( $row = fgetcsv($handler,1000) ) !== FALSE ){

    // insert a row
    $firstname = $row[0];
    $lastname = $row[1];
    $email = $row[2];
    $stmt->execute();

}

} catch(PDOException $e)
    {
    echo "Error: " . $e->getMessage();
    }
$conn = null;
```

Using PDO is a good practice... you can try how fast it is. As long as your CSV won't have more than 50,000 that script I shared to you will work perfectly as what you want.

You don't need to use LOAD DATA INFILE if your CSV file isn't that Big. Especially if you want to do extra work before inserting the data while fetching from CSV.